# Can you delay in the surprise round?

Tags: dnd-4e

Is it permitted to delay your turn when you're an unsurprised combattant in the surprise round?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

There is nothing to prevent this in the surprise or delay rules. Delaying is a free action, which you can take during a surprise round with one exception (you can't use an action point during a surprise round).

The only consequence here is that you end up in a later spot in the initiative order.

You can *also* ready an action during a surprise round, as you are allowed to both take a standard action (the action type for ready), and an immediate actions (which is the type of action the trigger is).